# Replace placeholder in template with php function

Tags: php, regex, replace

Short and clear. I'm not good at regex because I never understood it. But when you look at this simple template, would you say it's possible to replace the %% + the content of it with php brackets + add function brackets to it like this:

Template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>%getTitle%</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='mainStream'>
        %getLatestPostsByDate%
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It should replace it to this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php getTitle();?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='mainStream'>
        <?php getLatestPostsByDate();?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible? If yes, how? If anyone got a good tutorial for regEx which explains it even for not so smart guys, I'd be very thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use str_replace

Comment: `I'm not good at regex because I never understood it.`  I don't like this sentence.... maybe you meant `because I am lazy to learn it.` ?

Comment: Thanks for the links :) I'll definately learn it since you need it like everyday if you're coding. No matter how long I just did this without knowing how to regex. It's so important. Thank you all very much! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a good start. Get all between your custom tags (%%), and replace it with php code.

https://regex101.com/r/aC2hJ3/1

regex: `/%(\w*?)%/g`. Check explanation of regex at the right hand side (top), and generated code... it should help.

```
$template=file_get_contents('template.php');

    $re = "/%(\\w*?)%/"; 

    $subst = "<?php $1(); ?>"; 

    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $template);

file_put_contents('template.php',$result);
```

Comment: Dude, I love you :> This seems like the best solution for me, not like the other answers are bad, they are also good, but your's is the best explanation to me. Thank you very much. Just for the more dynamic part, instead of file_put_contents Im using a trick to not manipulate the template -> eval('?>' . $result . '<?php');

regards

Comment: Np, glad to help. :) regex101 is probably one of the best online resources for learning and practicing regex, and sometimes even a source of ready-made solutions to problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$html = str_replace ('%getLatestPostsByDate%', '<?php getLatestPostsByDate();?>', $html);
```

If, however you are looking for a generic solution then you have to use **regex**